# Get SVG path id using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I am having a svg file ,there i need to get the particular path id using javascript or jquery.
How can i do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("svg").click(function(){

$(this).find("#lay7").css("fill",color);

});
});
```

Instead of giving id ("lay7") of path directly i need to get the id dynamically.

REf:http://jsfiddle.net/BKAHg/

Comment: Based on what? The element that was clicked, or something else?

Comment: Yes i want to get the id based on the click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the $(this) object itself. Oh and you want to attach the click handler to the path I imagine too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("path").click(function(){

$(this).css("fill",color);

});
});
```

Comment: I tried this ,This colors the entire SVG, but i need to color the particular part based on clicked path id.

Comment: Probably best if you showed more code ideally create a jsfiddle and make it clearer what you want. It's not possible to have multiple colours on a single path though except via a gradient or a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("svg").delegate("*", "click", function(e) { $(this).css('fill', color) })
```

Comment: Thaks a lot .This works for me with only one small problem .This one colors the out line too.I want only my path to be colored